# typescript compiler error: Cannot convert '{}[]' to 'Array'

Tags: typescript, tsc

I'm having compiler errors with  this typescript code:)

I've defined playerBullets like so:

```
playerBullets: Array = Array[40];
```

and try to do this:

```
this.playerBullets = this.playerBullets.filter(function (bullet) {
    return bullet.active;
});
```

but this code has been market with red syntax errors:

> WebUI/ts/game.ts(89,19): Expected var, class, interface, or module
>   WebUI/ts/game.ts(88,29): Cannot convert '{}[]' to 'Array'

If I change the definition to this:

```
playerBullets  = [];
```

it works, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the array like this:

```
playerBullets: bullet[] = new Array(40);
```

And the overall code will look like this:

```
interface bullet{
     active :bool;
}

var playerBullets:bullet[] = new Array(40)

playerBullets = playerBullets.filter( function (bullet) {
    return bullet.active;
});
```

---

Of course you don't have to define the bullet type (but if you use typescript you probably want)

```
var playerBullets:any = new Array(40)

playerBullets = playerBullets.filter( function (bullet) {
    return bullet.active;
});
```